# What powers did the Black Sky have?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-2015, the-defenders-2017

As revealed on *Daredevil*, and mentioned many times on *The Defenders*,

> Elektra is a Black Sky.

This leads the Hand to put a lot of faith in her ability to lead them to victory.

But what powers does this actually give her? It was often hard to tell in the fight scenes. Speed? Superhuman strength? Skill at combat? Or something more?

Comment: She has the power of....... suspense!

Comment: She has the power of....... clouds! At night-time!

Comment: She has the power of....... prophecy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Speculative answer:

Personally I believe it is not about the supernatural power but it is more akin to "having power to do something" - in this example  "The Black Sky has the power to defeat the K'un-L'un and the Iron Fist". We don't have proofs of that, but it seems that there must exist a prophecy/belive of some sort, since both sides (The Hand and Chaste) deeply believe that the Black Sky is dangerous.

And this is exactly what has happened: Electra was able to incapacitate Randy and manipulate him into breaking the seal, which would give the Hand enough power to return from exile - in other words "The Black sky had the power to bring the Hand to victory".

Answer (score 2):

No one knows what the black sky actually does as it has never been explained and there’s a reason for that “bait and hook” even. “Stick” said that The Hand has never been able to get their hands on one until Electra.

Remember that Electra only recently found out that she was one of the black skies. Nabo said that they are extremely rare so there is more than one. That kid being killed at the shipyard was one of them.  The only thing we know is that they are not immortal; they can be killed.

I’m not sure if we will ever find out exactly the purpose of the black sky.  It has to be more than we currently know of because Electra has been beaten in battle and she has also died, so there is something untapped inside of her that needs to be released for the full potential of the weapon.

Answer (score 1):

Black Sky doesn't had any supernatural power. She was a skilled ninja and had excellent fighting skills with good human strength.